# strace -e trace=network only showing SIGCHLD?

Tags: linux, sockets, debugging, strace

I am using the command:

> strace -tt -o ${filename} -e trace=network gdb --args ${EXECUTABLE}

to track which system calls occur whilst connecting to and sending messages to a peer. However, I am only receiving the following entries:

```
15:40:11.908857 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=5019, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
15:40:11.911130 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=4987, si_status=SIGTRAP, si_utime=1, si_stime=0} ---
15:40:11.914907 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4987, si_status=0, si_utime=1779, si_stime=180} ---
15:40:11.963586 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=4983, si_status=SIGTRAP, si_utime=37, si_stime=4} ---
15:40:11.973691 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=5019, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
15:40:11.975929 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=4983, si_status=SIGTRAP, si_utime=37, si_stime=4} ---
15:40:11.979922 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4983, si_status=0, si_utime=1816, si_stime=184} ---
```

Should I not see the socket calls to `read()` `close()` etc?

Comment: Did you try to add `-f` in order to follow fork  ?

Comment: @mpromonet I didn't originally. Just tried strace -tt -f -o ${filename} -e trace=network gdb --args ${EXECUTABLE} but get Cannot create process: Operation not permitted. During startup program exited with code 127.

Comment: Why not using  `strace -f -tt -o ${filename} -e trace=network ${EXECUTABLE} ` without gdb ? With your command you are logging system call of gdb.

Comment: @mpromonet I did that in the end and it worked.  I can see recvfrom() etc. Put that as an answer and i'll accept. Many thanks.

Comment: Strace and gdb both use the ptrace system call to do their work, and Linux allows a process to have just one tracer at a time.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using strace with `gdb --args ${EXECUTABLE}` prints syscall of gdb, instead of syscall of the executable running under gdb.

In order to prints syscall of your executable you could use :

```
strace -f -tt -o ${filename} -e trace=network ${EXECUTABLE}
```

The '-f' option ask to strace to follow forks, this is useful when an executable fork new thread or new process.